# Plotting "None" values in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have a database which stores values every minute using a timestamp and a value for that timestamp. Sometimes the value is None. I have to plot these values using matplotlib.

I have tried passing simply the None value but when plotting, i get this error: 
"raise TypeError("{val!r} is not a string".format(val=val))
TypeError: None is not a string" so i ended up just replacing the None values with an empty string "". But this ends up plotting dots as "0" values which is incorrect for my purpose. I would like these values not to be represented.

My data is stored as dictionaries with list values.

This is my code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import sys
import datetime
import numpy


class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        pass


class MyDynamicMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        MyMplCanvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.lines = []
        self.labels = []
        self.update_figure()

    def update_figure(self):
        processed_numeric_values = {'0022FF0000000680_6': ['16.97', '16.97', '16.97', '', '16.97', '16.97', '16.97', '16.97'], '0022FF0000000680_7': ['16.97', '16.97', '16.97', '', '16.97', '16.97', '16.97', '16.97'], '0022FF0000000680_13': ['1.00', '1.00', '1.00', '', '1.00', '1.00', '1.00', '1.00'], '0022FF0000000680_14': ['0.99', '0.99', '0.99', '', '1.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.99']}

        processed_time_values = {'0022FF0000000680_6': [datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 23), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 24), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 25), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 26), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 27), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 28), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 29), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 30)], '0022FF0000000680_7': [datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 23), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 24), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 25), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 26), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 27), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 28), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 29), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 30)], '0022FF0000000680_13': [datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 23), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 24), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 25), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 26), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 27), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 28), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 29), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 30)], '0022FF0000000680_14': [datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 23), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 24), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 25), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 26), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 27), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 28), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 29), datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 3, 9, 30)]}

        for eui_attr in processed_numeric_values.keys():
            line, = self.axes.plot(numpy.array(processed_time_values[eui_attr]),
                               numpy.array(processed_numeric_values[eui_attr]),
                               visible=True,
                               marker='o', markersize=5, lw=2, label=eui_attr)
        self.labels.append(eui_attr)
        self.lines.append(line)
        if self.labels:
            self.axes.legend(loc=1, ncol=2, fontsize='xx-small', frameon=True, fancybox=True, facecolor=(0.7, 0.7, 0.7))
        self.draw()

class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setWindowTitle("application main window")

        self.main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)

        l = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        dc = MyDynamicMplCanvas(self.main_widget, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        l.addWidget(dc)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

        self.statusBar().showMessage("All hail matplotlib!", 2000)


qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
aw = ApplicationWindow()
aw.show()
sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
#qApp.exec_()
```

This is what i get now: [image]

This is what i want to achieve: [image]

I would like to maintain the dictionaries because they are part of a more complex code, just to replace the "" with None values so they are not interpreted as "0" values.

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT:

The data dictionaries are structured like this:

```
processed_numeric_values = {'0022FF0000000680_6': [numeric_values], '0022FF0000000680_7': [numric_values], '0022FF0000000680_13': [numeric_values], '0022FF0000000680_14': [numeric_values]}

processed_time_values = {'0022FF0000000680_6': [datetime_values], '0022FF0000000680_7': [datetime_values], '0022FF0000000680_13': [datetime_values], '0022FF0000000680_14': [datetime_values]}
```

The dictionaries contain the same keys and each key represents one line in the chart. The processed_numeric_values dictionary represents the data on the Y axis and processed_time_values dictionary represents the data on the X axis.

Comment: Could you please post a few sample lines of your data? Perhaps `y = numpy.array(processed_time_values[eui_attr])` and then `y[y==0] = np.nan` might help, but I'm not sure if I understand the structure and type of your data right.

Comment: Why do you store your values as strings? Maybe this problem is more about how you store and read your data?

Comment: I store them as dictionaries because i use the keys ("0022FF0000000680_6", "0022FF0000000680_7" and so on) to identify the plots. I will update the question with the dictionary structures for better understanding

Comment: The point is that you should not be plotting strings because strings do not allow for a "no value"-value. Use numbers instead where `None` works fine.

Comment: I have tried floating the numeric values before appending them to the lists but i still get this error: "raise TypeError("{val!r} is not a string".format(val=val))
TypeError: 16.96 is not a string" when plotting

Comment: Converting the strings to floats and replacing empty strings with `None` plots fine for me.

Comment: Actually you were right, it was a problem o data representation, works like a charm! And this actually solved another problem i was having.

Comment: Yes, clumsy me forgot to float the first value in the list. Thank you!